# Does every strip of positive irrational slope contain a perfect square point?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Does every strip between two parallel lines of positive irrational slope contain a point with perfect square coordinates? Equivalently (I think), are there perfect square points arbitrarily close to any positively irrationally sloped line?

EDIT: [wrong, retracted].

EDIT 2: Numerical experiments seem to hint at a **counterexample** for $\alpha = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} = (\phi -1)^2$. With $p_k/q_k$ being convergents of the continued fraction $[0;\overline{1}]$ for $\phi-1$, it seems that

$$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty}{\left|p_k^2-\alpha q_k^2\right|} = 0.55278\dots$$

so square points other than $(0,0)$ are at least that constant away *vertically* from $y = \alpha x$. Squared *perpendicular* distance from the points to the line seems to tend to a rational, $4/15$.

EDIT 3: The convergents in EDIT 2 are the ratios of consecutive Fibonacci numbers $F_n$. With the help of wxMaxima I managed to calculate:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left| {{\left(\phi-1\right)^2\ F_{n+1}^2}}-F_n^2\right| = \sqrt{\frac{6-2\sqrt{5}}{5}} ≈ 0.55278... > 0$$

which settles the general question negatively, and I'm nearly sure that a similar limit exists whenever the CF for $\sqrt{\alpha}$ is eventually periodic (i.e. $\alpha$ is a square of a quadratic irrational) — or more precisely, the smallest of a finite set of limits, one for each offset within the period.

Comment: If $\sqrt{\alpha}$ is close to $p/q$, then $\alpha$ is close to $p^2/q^2$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I'm not convinced. From the fact that $p^2/q^2$ can be arbitrarily close to α it doesn't seem to follow that $p^2-(αq^2+β)$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: Does every strip between two parallel lines of positive irrational slope contain a point with integer coordinates? I’m not seeing an obvious proof.

Comment: @Stella, I don't have a good reference at my fingertips, but "inhomogeneous diophantine approximation" is the keyphrase.

Comment: @Stella I think it's simpler to think of points close to line $αx+β$. Consider the sequence of points $(q_k, p_k)$ corresponding to convergents $p_k/q_k$ of the continued fraction expansion of α. The "error" $p_k - αq_k$ tends to $0$ and has either sign infinitely often, so eventually it will be absolute-smaller than β and of the same sign, giving you a point closer to the line than the origin. Treat that point as new origin, and it's clear that you can always find one closer to the line.

Comment: I think the problem with the example of EDIT 2 is that there is a (very) nearby point, namely $(0,0)$,

Comment: @S.Dolan, $(0,0)$ is _very_ near $y = \alpha x$ indeed :), but we're really interested in $y = \alpha x + \beta$, $\beta \neq 0$, and trying to decide whether there will always be a square point strictly _between_ those lines (which appears false in general).

Comment: just a quick update, I've verified and indeed the counterexample works for with like say $\beta=0.1$ or something small, I'll probably write out a proper proof of it soon

Answer (score 6):

As the answer is geting somewhat messy, here's a summary:

For all $\alpha>0,\beta\in\mathbb R,n>1$ and $\epsilon>0$, is there $p,q\in\mathbb N$ such that

$$\left|q^n\alpha+\beta-p^n\right|<\epsilon$$

For $n<2$, the answer is yes. For $n>2$, then we can find many counterexamples. In the case of $n=2$, it depends how well can $\sqrt\alpha$ be rationally approximated.

**Edit 2**

The edit here is just the discussion in the comments properly written out + more generality:

Let $\alpha$ be any irrational, and let $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be the continued fractions of $\alpha$. We know that they satisfy the following minimal property:

For all $0<q'\leq q_n$, we have $$\left|q_n\alpha-p_n\right|\leq\left|q'\alpha-p'\right|$$ and equality only holds when $q'=q_n,p'=p_n$. Note that this is one way to define the covergents of $\alpha$.

Define $$\varepsilon_q=\min_{0<p,0<q'\leq q}\left|q\alpha-p\right|$$

we note that the values of $\varepsilon_q$ are precisely those that comes from the continued fraction.

Suppose $\alpha,p,q>0$ and $\left|q^2\alpha^2-p^2\right|<\varepsilon$. We now have the following chain of inequalities (for small enough $\varepsilon$, i.e. $\varepsilon<q^2\alpha^2$):

\begin{align*}
\epsilon&>\left|q^2\alpha^2-p^2\right|\\
&=\left|q\alpha-p\right|\left|q\alpha+p\right|\\
&\geq\varepsilon_q\left(q\alpha+\sqrt{q^2\alpha^2-\varepsilon}\right)\\
&=\varepsilon_qq\alpha\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{\varepsilon}{q^2\alpha^2}}\right)\\
&\geq\varepsilon_qq\alpha\\
\end{align*}

and by choosing $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$, we know that the convergents must be given by $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ where $F_n$ is the Fibbonaci sequence. With some effort, we can show that

\begin{align*}
\varepsilon_{F_n}&=\left|F_n\alpha-F_{n+1}\right|\\
\varepsilon_{F_n}F_n&=\left|\frac1{\sqrt5}\left((-1)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n}\right)\right|\\
&\geq\frac{3-\sqrt5}2\approx0.382
\end{align*}

which approaches $\frac1{\sqrt5}$ as $n\to\infty$. This shows that

$$\left|q^2\alpha^2-p^2\right|\geq\left(\frac32-\frac{\sqrt5}2\right)\alpha=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$$ .

Hence

$$\left|q^2\alpha^2+\beta-p^2\right|\geq\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}-|\beta|$$

and if we choose any $|\beta|<\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$, then the quantity $\left|q^2\alpha^2+\beta-p^2\right|$ will never get arbitrarily close to $0$ for any $p,q\in\mathbb Z$

Note: By requiring $\varepsilon_qq$ doesn't eventually reach $0$, this is slightly stronger than asking for the irrationality measure to be $2$ (all irrational algebraic integers have irrationality measure $2$ - see Roth's theorem). It may be interesting to study what happens when the irrationality measure is above $2$, or even say $\alpha$ is some Liouville number. The bounding would certainly be much harder but it could be doable? Another thing that this technique can't work on is when $|\beta|$ is reasonably big which may be interesting to look at as well.

Note that we can also bound in the other direction to see what numbers `works':

\begin{align*}
&\left|q_n\alpha-p_n\right|\left|q_n\alpha+p_n\right|\\
\leq&\varepsilon_{q_n}\left(2q_n\alpha+\varepsilon_{q_n}\right)\\
=&2q_n\varepsilon_{q_n}\alpha+\varepsilon_{q_n}^2\\
\end{align*}

and if $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n\varepsilon_{q_n}=0$, we see that $\left|q_n^2\alpha^2-p_n^2\right|\to0$ as well. A classical result (that isn't too hard to prove) is that the sign of $q_n\alpha-p_n$ is $\pm(-1)^n$, which directly tells us that for any $\beta,\epsilon$, we can find some $p,q\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\left|q^2\alpha^2+\beta-p^2\right|<\epsilon$ (Hint: Split the case for $\beta>0$ and $\beta<0$, and multiply $q^2\alpha^2+\beta-p^2$ by $n^2$ for an appropriate $n$).

From the discussion in the previous paragraph, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon_{q_n}q_n>0\iff\exists\beta$ where we cannot approximate $\left|q^2\alpha^2+\beta-p^2\right|$ arbitrarily well.

**Previous attempt - solution for exponent $>2$ with some 'size' bounds**

Not quite the answer but hopefully it can be modified to work, so far this only works if the exponent is above $2$:

For some strip given by $\alpha x+\beta_1,\alpha x+\beta_2$, if we want to find some $(q^2,p^2)$ in it, it is equivalent to asking for $\left|\alpha q^2+\frac{\beta_1+\beta_2}2-p^2\right|<\frac{\left|\beta_1-\beta_2\right|}2$, hence it is sufficient to show if for all $\alpha,\beta,\epsilon$, do there exists $p,q$

$$\left|\alpha q^2-\beta-p^2\right|<\epsilon$$

However we want to omit the trivial cases which occurs where $\alpha,\beta$ are rational, hence a better question is perhaps for 'almost all $\alpha,\beta$'. This suggests the following approach:

Choose some $f$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=1$.

Fix $p,q,\epsilon$, we find the measure of all possible $\alpha,\beta$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\alpha q^2-p^2-\epsilon}^{\alpha q^2-p^2+\epsilon}fd\beta fd\alpha$$

then if for some $\epsilon$ we have

$$\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\alpha q^2-p^2-\epsilon}^{\alpha q^2-p^2+\epsilon}fd\beta fd\alpha<1$$
we would be done.

The hope is that since $p^2,q^2$ 'grows quite quickly', the sum converges.

For instance, say we choose $f(x)=\frac12\text{sech}^2(x)$, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{\alpha q^2-p^2-\epsilon}^{\alpha q^2-p^2+\epsilon}fd\beta&=\frac12\tanh\left(\alpha q^2-p^2+\epsilon\right)-\frac12\tanh\left(\alpha q^2-p^2-\epsilon\right)\\
&=\frac{\sinh(2\epsilon)}{\cosh\left(2(p^2-q^2\alpha)\right)+\cosh(2\epsilon)}
\end{align*}

and this gives us the following sum:

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\alpha q^2-p^2-\epsilon}^{\alpha q^2-p^2+\epsilon}fd\beta fd\alpha\\
=&\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac12\frac{\text{sech}^2(\alpha)\sinh(2\epsilon)}{\cosh\left(2(p^2-q^2\alpha)\right)+\cosh(2\epsilon)}d\alpha\\
=&\frac12\sinh(2\epsilon)\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\text{sech}^2(\alpha)}{\cosh\left(2(p^2-q^2\alpha)\right)+\cosh(2\epsilon)}d\alpha\\
<&\frac12\sinh(2\epsilon)\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\text{sech}^2(\alpha)}{\cosh\left(2(p^2-q^2\alpha)\right)+1}d\alpha\\
=&\frac14\sinh(2\epsilon)\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text{sech}^2(\alpha)\text{sech}^2(p^2-q^2\alpha)d\alpha\\
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, the $\sum_{p=1}^\infty$ seems to numerically be about $\frac1q$, which means the sum diverges and we need a better choice of $f$.

Interestingly, if we use $(q^3,p^3)$ instead, numerical evidence shows that the sum grows like $\frac1{q^2}$ which does converge, so this method may still be viable.

If all else fails, we could still obtain interesting results by setting say $\epsilon$ as a function of $p$ or $q$ which gives us some bounds on what is possible and what isn't.

**Edit**

With a bit more playing around, I think I got a clearer sketch in this case. This shows that the result holds for $(q^{2+\epsilon},p^{2+\epsilon})$ for $\epsilon>0$, not quite what we want but close.

Let $n=2+\epsilon$ as above, our goal now is to show the following term is finite:

$$\sum_{p=1}^\infty\sum_{q=1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text{sech}^2(\alpha)\text{sech}^2(p^n-q^n\alpha)d\alpha$$

We note that $\text{sech}^2(x)<e^{-2|x|}$. This simplfies our integral down to

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text{sech}^2(\alpha)\text{sech}^2(p^n-q^n\alpha)d\alpha\\
<&\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2|\alpha|}e^{-2\left|p^n-q^n\alpha\right|}d\alpha\\
=&\frac{e^{-2\left(\frac pq\right)^nq^n}-e^{-2p^n}}{2q^{-2n}-2}
\end{align*}

When summing over $p,q$, the $$\frac{-e^{-2p^n}}{2q^{-2n}-2}$$ term converges. The other term can be shown to converge with the following bound:

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{p=1}^\infty e^{-2\left(\frac pq\right)^n}\\
<&\int_0^\infty e^{-2\left(\frac pq\right)^n}dp\\
=&2^{-\frac1n}q^{-1}\Gamma\left(1+\frac1n\right)\\
\end{align*}

and we're done since $$\sum_{q=1}^\infty\frac{q^{n-1}}{2q^{-2n}-2}$$ converges for $n>2$.

To summarize, this tells us that if we take any $n>2$, we can find $\epsilon$ small enough such that there exists some positive measure of $\alpha,\beta$ where the following inequality is never true for any $p,q\in\mathbb Z$:

$$\left|\alpha q^n-\beta-p^n\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll sit down to those rigorous integrals and gammas eventually, but I think there's a simpler if fuzzier geometric intuition: if you raise the coordinates to $1/n$, then for $n=2$ the parallel half lines turn into "parallel" quarter-hyperbolas and the area between them is infinite, so it has "ample opportunity" to eventually capture an integer point $(q,p)$ that corresponds to $(q^n,p^n)$ before the change of coordinates. However for $n>2$ the area between the curves is finite.

Comment: ... aaand just to add that $\alpha$ being a square of a quadratic irrational (like in the counterexample I gave) can also be treated as a trivial case.

Comment: It will take a while before I can understand a sum of sums of integrals of integrals, and I know very little about measure, so I've never heard of using calculus like this to compute the measure of a set. The free-ish choice of function $f$ feels particularly 3deep5me. What do I google?

Comment: In particular, _if_ my intuition in the first comment is in fact equivalent to (a special case of) this calculus technique, then what is $f$ in that case?

Comment: Oh I think I'm beginning to get it. We use $f$ to "sense" how near the miss was, then we integrate that for all $\beta$ in the interval of interest that depends on $\alpha$, then we integrate _that_ for all $\alpha$, and finally we sum it for all p and q. Right?

Comment: Hmm, $sech^2(x) < e^{-2\left|x\right|}$? That doesn't look right, but the limit of the ratio is $4$ so perhaps this can be fixed easily?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski the idea is that we want to find the "area" of all possible $(\alpha,\beta)$, however since $(-\infrt,\infty)$ has infinite length, we want to 'weight' the interval to get something finite, thats why we use $\int fdx$ instead of $\int dx$

Comment: $\cosh(x)=\frac12\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)\geq e^{|x|}$ the limit of the quotient you mentioned at infinity is $4$ but really in analysis stuff as long as the inequality holds we don't really care how bad is it :p

Comment: I'll verify the negative result at home probably, still at chinese new year visiting 

Comment: Happy New Year then! And I think I just might have a proof of negative result for any $\alpha = (quadratic\ irrational)^2$. Idea: $(q^2, p^2, qp)$ are integer points on cone $xy-z^2=0$, and the problem corresponds to the intersection line for $\alpha$ of that cone with plane through $(0,0,0), (1,\alpha,\sqrt{\alpha}), (1,\zeta,\sqrt{\zeta})$ where $\sqrt{\zeta}$ is the conjugate of $\sqrt{\alpha}$. I'll show elementarily that the plane is rationally oriented, thus all integer points $(x,y,z)$ including those on the cone are at rational, _commensurate_ $y$-distances from it.

Comment: ... and those _on_ the cone, other than $(0,0,0)$ are obviously _not_ on the plane due to irrationality of $\alpha$. Combined with commensurality of the distances, this proves a positive lower bound on the distance, QED.